# Magento 1.7 integrating custom admin module with attributes

Tags: magento, module, magento-1.7

I'm working on a clothing website and require all products to be tagged under a brand, and that brand needs its own logo, title and description with potential for more data in the future such as url's. I contemplated creating it as a category, however because products are also required to be listed regardless of brand i can not do this.

While looking around I looked into making admin modules, I'm not sure if this is at all the right avenue to research into (thanks to horrible documentation on Magentos part). Is it possible to make an admin module, where a user can create a new brand, give it an image description etc, and have this populate a product attribute dropdown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, but a full explanation would be too much for the SO format.

Look into the following topics:

- custom models for your data
- admin grids for managing it
- source models for the dropdown